# Error reloading tif while exporting raster to tif using gdal in python

Tags: python-2.7, tiff, raster, gdal

I want to export my processed raster layer which are np arrays as tif with following steps, after creating the out.tif raster with the driver I could not load the created tif file back into python. I tried to change the 'gdal.GDT_Int32' into other types but it didn't work. I also tried using instead of 'inds.GetDriver' 'GetDriverByName('GTiff') but that also didn't make any changes, messages as below:

```
In [13]: driver.Create('out.tif', cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Int32)
Out[13]: <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 
'GDALDatasetShadow *
' at 0x000000000F437360> >

In [18]: outds=gdal.Open('out.tif')
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-82ed958ff66e> in <module>()
----> 1 outds = gdal.Open('out.tif')

RuntimeError: `out.tif' not recognised as a supported file format.
```

or

```
In [14]: outds = gdal.Open('out.tif')
ERROR 4: `out.tif' not recognised as a supported file format.
```

My code:

```
#load inds for processing
inds = gdal.Open('in.tif', gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

cols = inds.RasterXSize
rows = inds.RasterYSize
driver = inds.GetDriver()


driver.Create('out.tif', cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Int32)
**#The step with errors!**
**outds = gdal.Open('out.tif')**
outband = outds.GetRasterBand()
data = inds.GetRasterBand().ReadAsArray()

outds.SetGeoTransform(inds.GetGeoTransform())
outds.SetProjection(inds.GetProjection())

outband = outds.GetRasterBand()
outband.WriteArray(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is solved with the same method used in this discussion:
[python-GDAL Write Array-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791233/gdal-writearray-issue)

By modifying the code this way:

```
outds = driver.Create('day.tif', cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Int32)
```

instead of in the preview post:

```
driver.Create('out.tif', cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Int32)
outds = gdal.Open('out.tif')
```

The error was solved.